# Type of statistics test to run?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-test

I have a between-subjects study design with two factors - Data Distribution (3 types) and Question Type (3 types). The experiment was a 3 (data distribution) x 3 (question types) design, with each trial having 4 possible choices. The 4 choices is the only thing that each subject sees, with the data distribution and question type between-subject.

The question is - what type of stats test should I run to test the affect of the two independent factors (Data distribution and Question type) on the user's preference of one of the 4 choices?

An ANOVA test probably won't be applicable here as the subject's response is not a single numerical response like time, but rather 1 out of 4 choices shown to him/her.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit of an advanced method, but I think it's the one that makes the most sense. You want to run a multinomial logistic regression model with Distribution, Type, and their interaction as predictors and choice as the dependent variable. The coefficients in the model are a bit hard to interpret (and you'll get many coefficients from such a model), but it's straightforward to test whether either of the factors or their interaction are related to the outcome. You can use likelihood ratio tests to choose between models that have the factor or interaction of interest and those that don't. Significant values for this test indicate that the factor does predict the choice. This is the same procedure you would use if you were to use a linear regression on a continuous outcome and weren't using an ANOVA procedure (though mathematically it's equivalent to ANOVA if parameterized correctly).

Comment: Thanks for responding!  What about something simpler such as running Chi-square tests for each of the two independent variables? Would it then be possible to compare the distributions - expected (25-25-25-25) vs. actual?